# PHP cant show result from SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, arr

I have a problem with sql. I am trying echo my SQL result but its not showing with my code. How can I echo `35000` and also convert this Thousand K like `35K`? Thanks

```
$billings_sum = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(bl_currency) from billings WHERE bl_user = '$user_id'" );

var_dump($billings_sum[0]);
```

**I am trying with this code.**

```
echo $billings_sum[0]["SUM(bl_currency)"];
```

**Var_dump result:**

```
object(stdClass)#709 (1) {
  ["SUM(bl_currency)"]=>
  string(5) "35000"
}
```

Comment: you should rename the SUM() with as "currency" and then ["currency"]

Comment: @Joel Garcia Nuño can you give me an example?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(bl_currency) as currency ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Curly brackets like `{}` follow the below code

```
echo $billings_sum[0]->{'SUM(bl_currency)'};
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Execuse me, curly brackets are available in all version's of php ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the output you got is in "object" form. To access the object value you need to go like this -

```
$billings_sum = (object) array(
    'SUM(bl_currency)' => 35000
);

echo $billings_sum->{'SUM(bl_currency)'};
```

Hope that helps.

Regards, Shahriar :)

Comment: Its static. I want dynamically show the result from sql

Comment: Just use this line - "echo $billings_sum[0]->{'SUM(bl_currency)'};"

Comment: @IronFist Your answer is partially right like `echo $billings_sum->{'SUM(bl_currency)'};` but you have defined some extra works like `$billings_sum = (object) array(
    'SUM(bl_currency)' => 35000
);` that not need actually because the user already posted his work & he just need to output, so remember this for next time answers. +1

Comment: @fool-dev thank you for pointing out issue. I will definitely try to avoid that next time. :)